# gnome-session-quit makes qt / kde applications crash

Tags: gnome, kde, crash, qt

Ubuntu 20.10, Groovy Gorilla, gnome 3.38.

When I launch `gnome-session-quit` using shortcut or by cli, KDE / QT applications crash.
I have tested kdenlive, kvantummanger, copyq.

The following is kdenlive's error message.

```
deleting core
QMutex: destroying locked mutex
qrc:/qml/timeline.qml:288: TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of null
qrc:/qml/timeline.qml:303: TypeError: Cannot read property 'seekFinished' of null
kdeinit5: PID 40803 terminated.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What's happening here?